# Sending String Through ObjectOutputStream JAVA Networking

Tags: java, object, networking, tcp

I'm trying to send a string through the objectOutputStream and I keep getting a null pointer Exception Error The code that's failing is here

```
try
      { // get username from text field and encrypt

        String uname = username.getText();
        EncryptMess logonU = new EncryptMess(uname); //Sends to be encrypted

        logonU.encrypt(); //Ecryption is ran
        String sendUname = logonU.getMessage(); // String is returned

        // get password from password field and encrypt
        String pword = password.getText();
        EncryptedMessage logonP = new EncryptedMessage(pword);

        logonP.encrypt();
        String sendPword = logonP.getMessage();

        // This prints out the encrypted messages perfectly, put in to troubleshoot
        System.out.println("1) " + sendUname + "\n2)" + sendPword + "\n");
        // send encrypted username to server

        clientOutputStream.writeObject(logonU.getMessage());

        // send encrypted password to server

        clientOutputStream.writeObject(logonP.getMessage());


    }
```

Then I get this error for the line where it is writing the object to the socket firstly I get this coming up as a console error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Chat_Client.sendLoginDetails(Chat_Client.java:282)
```

Comment: Do not do networking on the ui thread. But that is not the problem. Did you try to find out what in fact is null. The message is pretty explicit on that.

Comment: Line 282 is  clientOutputStream.writeObject(logonU.getMessage()); 

I tried to see if any of the variables being sent were null but they are all printing out to the console fine

Comment: How do you create clientOutputStream object?

Comment: `con = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 6000);
clientInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(con.getInputStream());
 clientOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());`

Comment: Send the whole error stack trace. If logonU.getMessage() and clientOutputStream are not null, there is too few information to say anything more.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Chat_Client.sendLoginDetails(Chat_Client.java:282)
 at Chat_Client$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(Chat_Client.java:508)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)

Answer (score 0):

Either 'clientOutputStream`or`logonU` is null.